# Docker on Windows server 2016 stuck on running image, Syscall timeout in event viewer

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I've installed Docker on Windows server 2016 following [these](https://docs.docker.com/install/windows/docker-ee/) instructions. The client hangs when I try to run the hello-world image

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run hello-world:nanoserver-sac2016
Unable to find image ‘hello-world:nanoserver-sac2016’ locally
nanoserver-sac2016: Pulling from library/hello-world bce2fbc256ea:
Pull complete 6f2071dcd729: Pull complete 909cdbafc9e1: Pull complete
a43e426cc5c9: Pull complete Digest:
sha256:878fd913010d26613319ec7cc83b400cb92113c314da324681d9fecfb5082edc
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:nanoserver-sac2016
```

Then, it sits there for ever. In the windows event viewer, I can see the following warning for source docker.

> Syscall did not complete within operation timeout. This may indicate a
>   platform issue. If it appears to be making no forward progress, obtain
>   the stacks and see if there is a syscall stuck in the platform API for
>   a significant length of time. cid= timeout=4m0s

Docker version

> Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise Version: 19.03.5 API version: 1.40
>   Go version: go1.12.12 Git commit: 2ee0c57608 Built: 11/13/2019
>   08:00:16 OS/Arch: windows/amd64 Experimental: false
>
> Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise Engine: Version: 19.03.5 API
>   version: 1.40 (minimum version 1.24) Go version: go1.12.12 Git commit:
>   2ee0c57608 Built: 11/13/2019 07:58:51 OS/Arch: windows/amd64
>   Experimental: false

`docker ps -a` shows that a container has been created from the image with status `Created`. Trying to start it also hangs the client.

How can I obtain the stack pointed out by event viewer? What could my installation or OS be missing?

Comment: This is a cross-post: https://forums.docker.com/t/new-install-docker-enterpise-on-windows-2016-cant-run-docker-run-hello-world/83966/2

Comment: For me, the issue was Symantec Endpoint protection interfering with docker. Its reported here.
https://support.symantec.com/us/en/article.tech246815.html

Now the security team is working on the mentioned exceptions and updates. I'll update here if it works out.